# How to keep an edit from "taking over question"

Tags: discussion, editing

A user submitted a poorly worded question which was already downvoted:

> detect forged e-mail system for windows?
>
> some instances people send emails with false or "forged" headers. How
>   can detect forged e-mail? (some program in windows) thanks in adv.
>   aghusa#112

I thought I was following the edit guidelines to "be substantial and to leave the post better than you found it" and "To fix grammar and spelling mistakes" and "clarify the meaning of the post (without changing that meaning)" and "add related resources or hyperlinks" with my edit:

> I
>   sometimes receive emails with false or "forged" headers. There are a
>   lot of [online
>   guides](http://email.about.com/cs/spamgeneral/a/spam_headers_2.htm)
>   that have tips and techniques for
>   [detecting](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/tech-tip-examine-e-mail-headers-to-determine-forgery/)
>   these forged headers but they require a human to examine the headers.
>
> Is there any Windows program that can parse email headers and detect
>   when they are false or forged either automatically as email is
>   received or that I can run on specific suspicious looking messages to
>   look for these headers?

But my edit was rejected with the reason: "takes over the question" by a moderator who edited it himself to:

> some instances people send emails with false or "forged" headers. How
>   can detect forged e-mail? (some program in windows)

Which still seems to be a low quality question with grammar mistakes.

I don't believe that I changed the meaning of the question, and I gave some supporting background to make it more clear. What do the edit guidelines when they mean "edits should be substantial"? I usually avoid making small one or two word changes just because the edit guidelines say not to, so I try to make more substantial edits. Am I misunderstanding the intent of  the "edits should be substantial" guideline?

Answer (score 6):

I would suggest your first paragraph is the problem here.

While you may think that you are providing useful information, it is a dramatic change to the question. Your second paragraph is absolutely fine - I'd mark it as a good edit - but please don't make major changes to the question that the OP never intended.

Seeing those links and comments as part of an answer post could definitely be appropriate.

Comment: Ahh interesting, I didn't think that posting links that describe the "forged header" problem was changing the question at all. In any case, his question is now closed as being too vague. Since he's clearly a non-english speaker, it's doubtful if he's going to make any meaningful edits himself, but I'll give him some more time then I'll post my edited version as a new question, as I do think it's a good question. Thanks!